# Input file accept only text/vtt mime types

Tags: validation, input, mime

I am trying to make input file accept webvtt subtitles, however if I do this:

```
<input type="file" name="sub_upload" accept="text/vtt">
```

It still shows other files along vtt extension in file browse window. Is there a way to filer files with only vtt extension?

Comment: Found a partial answer, I can just say accept=".vtt">

Answer (score 7):

pretty late to answer this i know but this worked for me , hope it benefits someone

```
<input type="file" name="sub_upload" accept=".vtt"> // for showing only .vtt files

<input type="file" name="sub_upload" accept=".vtt,pdf,.srt"> //generally for showing only .vtt , .pdf,.srt files
```